# Passing empty or null Boolean parameter in jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

In jstl, we can declare a variable with empty value like below -

```
<c:set var="isCompleted" value=""/>
```

Now suppose, I have a tag named `testBoolean.tag` where I have a boolean attribute

```
<%@ attribute name="completed" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="true" %>
```

Clearly the type is Object boolean, so I should be able to pass null.

But when I pass an empty value to the tag -

```
<tagDir:testBoolean completed=${isCompleted}/>
```

it automatically converting empty to `False`!

Is there any way we can pass null to boolean attribute here?

Comment: Looks like boolValue is a primitive `boolean` not  an object `Boolean`

Answer (score -1):

In your custom tag you must have given type of boolValue as boolean which by default makes it false if no value is provided or the string is anything other than true. If you want exact value which you set, try making its type as String.

Comment: Is that expected behavior given that my attribute type is java.lang.Boolean

Comment: Yes, that's expected. Any String other then "true" will evaluate to false by Boolean wrapper class. For the expected behavior which you need, keep the type as string and then you can do the manipulation on that in your custom tag.

Comment: If you go with java convention, that can't be the ideal behavior as because Boolean can be null.
And regarding your suggested solution, If that is the implementation of attribute type handling, i agree with you that i have to pass string.